# read word in column and copy cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code to look for the word "it" in column B.Then if the code finds it, it copies the cell to the right of it to another worksheet. Would anyone know how to modify it so it reads the second "it" in column B, not the first? Thank you

```
Dim rcell As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each rcell In Range("B2:B" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count + 1)
If rcell.Value = "it" Then
    rcell.Offset(, 1).Copy Sheets("another sheet").Range("C" & Rows.count).End(3)(2)
    End If
Next rcell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by "reads the second "it" in column B, not the first?" do you mean to say skip the first occurence of "it"? If so,  then just add a counter in your loop and another `If` statement which will trigger if `Count` is > 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim rcell As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each rcell In Range("B2:B" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count + 1)
Dim place%
'find first instance of "it"
place = InStr(1,rcell.Value, "it")
If place <> 0 Then
    'if there is one, check to see if there is a second instance
    'line below may have to use place+1 instead of just place
    If InStr(place,rcell.Value, "it") <> 0 Then
        rcell.Offset(, 1).Copy Sheets("another sheet").Range("C" & Rows.count).End(3)(2)
    End If
End If
Next rcell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```